# Why MySQL PDO UPDATE query doesn't update data in table?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

Here is yet another one question about mysql pdo update syntax. I've searched in previous questions posted in different resources such as Stackoverflow, but still can't get my query work! Need some help over here.

```
  $allowed = array("col1","col2","col3");
  $values = $_POST['id'];

  $sql = "UPDATE mytable SET ".pdoSet($allowed,$values)." WHERE 
  id=?";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); 
  $stmt->execute([$values]);
```

**Update#1.**

1. Added my pdoSet() function;
2. Little edited previous code fragment, in particular changed id=:id part in query.

   ```
   function pdoSet($allowed, &$values) {
    $set = '';
    $values = array();
      foreach ($allowed as $field) {
         $set.="`".str_replace("`","``",$field)."`". "=:$field, ";
      }
   return substr($set, 0, -2); 
   }

   $allowed = array("col1","col2","col3");
   $values["id"] = $_POST['id'];

   $sql = "UPDATE mytable SET ".pdoSet($allowed,$values)." WHERE id=:id";
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); 
   $stmt->execute($values);
   ```

Comment: you should `implode()` your array with coma `,` But jury is out till you show us the `pdoSet()` function

Comment: If you're calling a function with pdoSet you should use the identifier $this. Also, have you tried to put your query directly in the db where you can test it? Maybe is just a syntax problem

Comment: this line `$stmt->execute([$values]);` makes no sense. values is just an integer

Comment: Please don't tell us your storry, just ask your question.

Comment: @Dirk Horsten, excuse me.

Comment: @Akintunde Olawale, if using $comma_separated = implode(",", $allowed); and then passing it it in ".pdoSet($comma_separated, $values)." gives error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=?' at line 1

Comment: @Akintunde Olawale added my pdoSet() function